# How to set  (Apple Logo) in WhatsApp Status?

Tags: whatsapp, emoji

I want to set this logo:  (Apple Logo) in my WhatsApp Status. It is work in iPhone or Web, but it's not working on a **Android phone**

Is it possible? If possible then tell me how?

I try using WhatsAppWeb and set Status "", but on a Android phone it display's it always like this: " "

Comment:  is only visible on Apple devices. So you can neither set in on an Android device, nor any Android-User will see it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Apple logo is at Unicode code point F8FF, which is in the [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas). That is: this is not an official Unicode symbol. If your font (or system) doesn't support it you won't see it. Of course, Android doesn't have this non-standard symbol (and neither does Windows, AFAIK).

In other words: there is no way to have the Apple Logo appear on all devices using Unicode text alone. You would need to send an image.

Comment: And neither does Linux -- I see the twitter "t" logo.